# Settings don't take effect immediately

Tags: android, android-activity, settings

Anytime i change my in-app-settings (with shared preferences) i have to use the back button and go back into the activity for the changes to take effect. I'd like them to take effect immediately. I tried to use

```
protected void onResume(){

super.onResume();

}
```

but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong? My settings activity is called by menu inflater and finished when i click on the save button.

Comment: Sorry, but if there is no proper answer i won't accept it. I don't want to mislead people who have the same problem like me. Maybe we can now start to find a solution for my problem? If it's a good answer i will definitely accept it.

Comment: A 60% improvement's good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to look out for:

1. You're writing the new settings to the same file as the one being used, and not a different one
2. Most people use local variables to store settings on a run to run basis. Make sure you update all of these after changing the settings. A good way to do this is to have a seperate method like updateUserChoices(), and have all the code like `boolean sound = settings.getBoolean();` in it. Then simply call this method at the beginning, and after you update the settings.